# Slide banner with css3

Tags: html, css

I have to create a banner using only css3. I have create a basic structure but it is not working like slide banner. I want to with the slide wait for 5 second then move further but now it is moving quickly. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/5224/)

```
.main{ width:500px; overflow:hidden; border:solid 1px #000; }
.banner { width:1500px; animation: myfirst 10s infinite 2s}
.one { float:left; background:#F00; height:200px; width:500px}
.two { float:left; background:#0F0; height:200px; width:500px}
.three { float:left; background:#00F; height:200px; width:500px}

@keyframes myfirst {
    from {margin-left: 0px;}
    to {margin-left:-1000px}
} 



<div class="main">
<div class="banner">
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "It is not working like slide banner". Please elaborate on how it should work. I think you're problem is the ease in-out timing function which is default, try `animation-timing-function: linear;`

Comment: I want each slide should wait for 5 second then move to next slide

Comment: @amit something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/mBBJM/5259/

Comment: @Danield: Yes something like that but can we increase slide wait time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might this solution help you.

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="one item"></div>
            <div class="two item"></div>
            <div class="three item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
.main {
        width: 500px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: solid 1px #000;
    }
    .banner {
        width: 1500px;
        /*animation: myfirst 15s infinite 2s*/
    }
    .one {
        float: left;
        background: #F00;
        height: 200px;
        width: 500px;
        animation: myfirst 15s infinite 2s;
    }
    .two {
        float: left;
        background: #0F0;
        height: 200px;
        width: 500px;
        animation: myfirst 15s infinite 2s;
    }
    .three {
        float: left;
        background: #00F;
        height: 200px;
        width: 500px;
        animation: myfirst 15s infinite 2s;
    }
    .item{
        position: relative;
    }
    @keyframes myfirst {
        0%{
            left: 0;
        }
        15%{
            left: 0;
        }
        30%{
            left: -500px;
        }
        45%{
            left: -500px;
        }
        60%{
            left: -500px;
        }
        75%{
            left: -1000px;
        }
        90%{
            left: -1000px;
        }
        100%{
            left: 0px;
        }
    }
```

you need to add -webkit animation your self.

Comment: That all I want, Now I understand the logic behind it. Thanx a ton.